# UpdateMulti with aggregation,sort and limit

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am new in mongoTemplate, and I have to execute this query:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
{$match:{param1:'1','gr.param2':'2',param3:'3'}},
{$sort:{date:-1}},
{$limit:1},
{$set:{'gr.pr1':'1'}}
])
```

I have tried to do this using this:

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("param1").is("1").and("gr.param2")
                    .is("2")
                    .and("param3")
                    .is("3")
                    .with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "date")).limit(1);
            
            Update update = new Update();
            update.set("gr.pr1","1");

            mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, "collection");
```

This query is returning me N results, but I only want 1 (the last date)

Do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related with `updateMulti` because that methods return the updated values, so you can try using `findAndModify`.

Something like this:

```java
YourCollection yourObjectData = mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, YourCollection.class);
```

You can read the [MongoDB Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#return-data) about returning data from `db.collection.findAndModify`.

Note that default `new` value is `false`.

In [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-tutorial) you can check examples for `updateMulti` and `findAndModify`.